# Unable to enable Ubuntu Advantage (ua)

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

I have added the ua token, but unable to enable the services, even with the command sudo ua enable .
[image: Terminal screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] to include the version of Ubuntu you're using.

Comment: How many times has this token been used in the past, and how many systems is it currently active on? 